# I cannot run my flutter app. It says Flutter requires Android SDK 28, and I have sdk 28

Tags: dart, flutter, sdk

when I run flutter doctor, it shows me the following errors:

```
Running flutter doctor...
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[?] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 27.0.3)
    X Flutter requires Android SDK 28 and the Android BuildTools 28.0.3
      To update using sdkmanager, run:
        D:/Tools/sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager "platforms;android-28" "build-tools;28.0.3"
      or visit https://flutter.io/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
    X Android license status unknown.
[?] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2017.1)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[?] VS Code (version 1.26.1)
[?] Connected device (1 available)
```

Comment: add plugin of flutter and dart...go to the android studio in the file section  in setting and search flutter plugin and dart plugin.

Comment: I already did this, but still show this error

Answer (score 14):

You need to download

1- Android SDK version 28

Android Studio -> SDK Manager -> SDK Platforms tab -> Select Android 9.0 Pie and press ok to download it

2- Android BuildTools version 28.0.3

Android Studio -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools tab -> Select Show Package Details -> Under Android SDK Build-Tools section select 28.0.3 and press ok to download it

3- then Create and run Project

4- If the problem is still present, add

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32
```

to your PATH variable

Do not create new variable for git but add them as I did one after another separating them by ;

Comment: I faced the same issue, even after installing Build Tools version 28.0.3, flutter doctor was giving the same error. I tried everything but nothing worked, however in the end when I installed android 9 (Pie), my error resolved.

Answer (score 5):

In Android Studio (v4.0.1) initial launch dialog, under Configure, select SDK Manager.

[image]

Select tab "SDK Tools".  Check the "Show Package Details" and then check "28.0.3", and click "Apply".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After hours of struggling, the only thing that worked for me on a Mac Book Pro was the following installation:

Android Studio > Configure > SDK Manager > Android SDK Location (Edit) > Android SDK Platform > Check API 30: Android 11:.0 (R).

After that, 'flutter doctor -v' switched the message to the following:

Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at /Users/Mac/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3

Answer (score 1):

In my case flutter doctor required: SDK 29 (Flutter requires Android SDK 29 and the Android BuildTools 28.0.3)

I fixed this issue by installing Android 10.0(Q)

[Android SDK Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9weX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Wow! I ended up back here, on my old answer, while trying to upgrade my flutter setup from 1.20.2 to 1.22.6, and `flutter doctor` reporting missing SDK:

[image]

Fixed by installing the Android SDK Command-line Tools:

[image]