# Flutter requires Android SDK 29 and the Android BuildTools 28.0.3 while having both

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

I try to install Flutter following official doc but when I run **flutter doctor** I have the following issue (which is my title):
[image: Flutter doctor error]

In Android studio I have the following SDK installed:

[image: Android SDK 29]

[image: Android BuildTool 28.0.3]

I checked these links but none helped me:

- [Flutter requires Android SDK 28 and the Android BuildTools 28.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59581051/flutter-requires-android-sdk-28-and-the-android-buildtools-28-0-3)
- [I cannot run my flutter app. It says Flutter requires Android SDK 28, and I have sdk 28](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55221029/i-cannot-run-my-flutter-app-it-says-flutter-requires-android-sdk-28-and-i-have/55345160)

Someone have an idea ?

Comment: If using command line, this worked to set the appropriate spec for me: 

Flutter Doctor: "Flutter requires Android SDK 29 and the Android BuildTools 28.0.3"

$ ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-29" "build-tools;28.0.3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After few hours working to solve this, I understand what was wrong and how to solve it.

In the file explorer, I went into **C:/Android/android-sdk/**.
In this folder, there is some folder but I looked at **build-tools/** and **platforms**.

In **build-tools** and I have the folder **28.0.3** which corresponds at Android BuildTools 28.0.3 so this one is good.

Then, in **platforms** folder, I only have **android-28** folder which means Android Studio didn't installed Android 29 correctly (I tried with android 26, 27 and 30 but none of these were installed correctly or in another folder). There is my main problem.

So I asked one of my friend to send me his **android-29** archive to unzip it into my **platforms** folder and then no more errors and I can use Flutter without trouble.

Answer (score 14):

I have tried to install all the required versions via SDK Manager but had little luck.
The thing that helped me was installing SDK via command line with `sdkmanager` utility.

Running this line fixed all problems:
`sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29"`

Comment: Coming here in July 2021 and I can tell you that this is most likely what you're looking for if you've already updated your SDK and Built Tools via Android Studio and `flutter doctor` is still telling you to update

Answer (score 9):

[Android Studio SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsNuz.png)

[SDK Components Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAggD.png)

Go to Android Studio SDK Manager, then click on EDIT (as shown in pic above).

Next, tick the API 31 setup to update (as shown in pic above). That's all. Hope it helps^^

Comment: Even if you don't tick the **API XX** option, it'll still show some pending downloads, which upon installing fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

Installing Android 10.0(Q) worked for me.

You can find it in ***SDK Manager -> Android SDK -> SDK platforms***

Comment: Worked for me as of April '23

Answer (score 1):

I upgrade the SDK manager SDK tools. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix the problem like this: Android studio - Android SDK, Edit Android SDK location and resolved reported issue: "An exiting Android SDK was detected..."

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. settup android 10.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing the concern.
Let me help you with this.
I was also getting the same error while setting up the flutter .

Just to share with you , first you have to check your android SDK location
check both **build tools** and **platform**

Both needs to have **28.0.3** in build tools and **29** in platform .

If anyone miss then you will get the error. You can check both and if 29 is not there and 28.0.3 there (mostly) then you can simply visit the android studio

Click on **SDK tools** and install the **Android 10 which is SDK 29 .**

Once installed , then you will have both 28.0.3 already and SDK 29 after installing.
After that run flutter doctor and there will be no error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

just go to andriod sdk manager and update the andriod sdk to above 28 api level